# Edit group by graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I try to edit group profile in Facebook by Graph API.

I try to use

```
POST graph.facebook.com
  /{node-id}?
    {updated-field}={new-value}&
    access_token={access-token}
```

but I think this can't help me.

What can I edit and is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group#update

You can´t change any group data, except if you created the group with the App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/app/groups#publish